# Facebook invite doesn't redirect to Page tab app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite

I have a facebook Page tab app, I sent invite to a user but that Invite opens in

```
https://apps.facebook.com/NAMESPACE,
```

I really want the `invite` to open in the same page tab App, I tried to change the `redirect_uri` while sending invite to `MYFACEBOOKPAGE?sk=app_APPID`

Anyone who can help me with that?

Comment: Invites are only available for apps in the Games category that have a canvas implementation.

Comment: @CBroe my app has that, and i am able to invite.. but I want to show the app on page tab instead of canvas

Comment: You are not allowed to automatically redirect between canvas and a page tab. Invites are for games on canvas only (and that means the game can actually be _played_ on canvas), and that is where you are supposed to handle them as well.